# Varnish greedy buffering

Tags: varnish

I have a setup with nginx proxy (ssl) to varnish (5.2) to apache on a debian linux.

varnish passing response without buffering to nginx (not buffering either)

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if ( std.integer(beresp.http.Content-Length, 0) > 10000 ) {
    set beresp.do_stream = true;
  }
}
```

If one downloads a big file (Ex: 8G), download start instantly (so stream seams to work) but varnish ram usage keeps growing.

Seems like varnish pulls form apache as fast as possible (faster then the output to the outer world) and steals all the ram needed.

If I get nginx to proxy directly to apache I don't have this issue.

Is there a way to tell varnish to limit it's buffering in this case?

Am I missing out something?

UPDATE

```
$ curl -i https://example.com/test.dmg | head

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2019 21:26:43 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-apple-diskimage
Content-Length: 8743924593
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 May 2014 16:18:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
X-Cache: MISS
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite your VCL and apparently working stream, your backend likely does *not* send `Content-Length` header.

You may want to ensure it does. Check [here](https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2014-October/024038.html).

Comment: Content-Length is set (it's static files, apache adds it automatically) and this line makes sure it's set `std.integer(beresp.http.Content-Length, 0) > 10000`

Comment: I think varnish tries to get data as fast as possible to have it available... but is there a way for it to limit this optimisation?

Comment: What had called my attention on this was seeing apache with 99% iowait and ram usage peeks

Comment: Well, not sure. But anyway, if this is a single server setup, you may just want to add an extra location block to your nginx so it can serve things directly for known static file types, e.g. `location ~ \.dmg$ { root /path/to/your/files/dir; # no proxy_pass here }` which would be good for performance reasons as well.

Comment: Thanks for advise... but I'm hosting ~100 websites, I can't go and hunt where they have their big files.  I can do it with a /find big files/ and fiddle in the mean time... I was hoping a solution would surface, or a setting I missed out.  At same time it's a security issue as it's then possible to chue up all the ram just initiating a get and pausing the connection after a few bites.  Thanks for your help Daniel.